# Email validator plugin in grails

Tags: java, grails

I am using **Grails 2.2.0** and **EmailValidator** version is **compile ":email-validator:0.1"**.
When I am doing like,Arg is String type and keep a valid mail id.

```
  EmailStatus status = emailValidatorService.check(arg)
```

But when I print `status` object properties then I get verified value `false`.Can  anyone suggest me why is this happening.I configured parameter in **Config.groovy** like

```
  emailvalidator.checkDomains = true
  emailvalidator.checkVRFY = true
```

I am trying to print like

```
 System.out.println("Domain  :"+status?.isDomainValid);  //Result is true
 System.out.println("Syntax  :"+status?.isSyntaxValid());  // Result is true
 System.out.println("Verified 1 :"+status?.isVerified());  // Result is false
```

Still it is not working.Please help me. How can I sort out this issue.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

As per the [documentation](https://github.com/tomaslin/grails-email-validator),

> Most mail servers will have the VRFY field disabled to prevent spam.
>   This means that in most cases, you won't know if an email address is
>   100% valid unless you send an email to it. The verified field of the
>   email status is going to most often be false

So I think you can turn off your verify settings to false,

```
emailvalidator.checkVRFY = false
```

Comment: any other solution to verify email id

Comment: you have to send a verification link to the mail id and get verified by the user. This is what most websites do.